# Doughnut with different arcs

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am trying to create a doughnut chart with react chartjs-2

Like this one :

[chartjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g07c1.png)

[image]

but chartjs doesn't provide this feature

Comment: you may want to try recharts: http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel

Comment: Thanks @VasylButov but it doesn't provide what i am looking for.